# EF6 joining self nested entities on a different column than the primary key column

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am using Entity Framework 6 and I have a rather original question, I have a tree structure like:

```
public TreeNode
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ExternalId { get; set; } // <-- this here is the join key
    public TreeNode ParentNode { get; set; }
    public int ParentNodeId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TreeNode> ChildrenNodes { get; set; } // <-- adding this
}
```

For whatever reason the old implementation which is already full of data and cannot be changed easily uses **ExternalId** instead of **Id** to join the Parent and the Child. I would now like to add a navigation property to be able to Include() all of the children of each node when fetching from the database but if I add a Fluent Configuration like:

```
        HasMany(sn => sn.ChildrenNodes)
            .WithOptional(sn => sn.ParentNode)
            .HasForeignKey(sn => sn.ParentNodeId);
```

This will obviously join the **ParentNodeId** on the **Id** not the **ExternalId**

Is there any way in EF6 to override the principal id of the relationship?

Comment: The short answer is - no. Such capability has been added only in EF Core.

Comment: ehh kidna thought so, I will wait and see if anyone has any other ideas. Seems I will just have to fetch it with round trips to the database and recursion.. which sounds.. very bad.